# Вывод цифровой клавиатуры с input

Tags: html5

Есть `<input type="number" id="guessField" class="guessField">`.
В процессе ввода цифр, на моб. устройствах открывается общая клавиатура.

Вот как сейчас:

[image: вот как сейчас]

А хочется:

[image: введите сюда код]

Вопрос: как выводить только цифровую клавиатуру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не устраивает `type="number"`, попробуйте использовать `type="tel"`. [Источник](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-forms-and-input-types)

Также, можете [поэкспериментировать](https://css-tricks.com/finger-friendly-numerical-inputs-with-inputmode/#article-header-id-2) с `inputmode="numeric"` (хотя, [поддержка](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-inputmode) пока оставляет желать лучшего).

В общем, универсального решения пока нет. Но, как вариант:

```
<input type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Comment: он не меняет стандартную клавиатуру

Comment: хотя pattern="[0-9]*" помог! Спасибо !